# reactivity disabling in meteor not loading data at first load

Tags: meteor, angular, publish, subscribe

i was making one subscription as nonreactive in meteor i am using angular2 for client side

reactivity disabling is working properly but i came up with an issue when i refresh the page the particular data i made {reactive:false} is not loading but if i navigate to any other view its coming if i am navigating from any other view also its. it have problem only at the first load. if i remove the {reactive:false} its working perfect

this is my code to publish

```
Meteor.publish("ThreesixtyMenu", function() {
    return ThreesixtyMenu.find({});

  });
```

and here the code how i subscribing it

```
 Meteor.subscribe('ThreesixtyMenu')
 this.menudata = ThreesixtyMenu.find({},{reactive:false})
 return this.menudata;
```

hoping quick solution,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `find` with `reactive: false` before the subscription is ready. It takes some time for the data to arrive at the client, so your `find` won't return anything until the data is there.

If you enable reactivity, `find` is called twice. The first invocation returns `undefined` (for the same reason as above), and the second one is triggered when the data from the subscription arrives, giving you the correct result.

*In summary:* without reactivity, you have to wait until the subscription is ready before fetching data.

Comment: thank you so much for this info. but can you please tell me how should i write the code if i am not calling find

Comment: I don't know how to integrate the solution in your code because I'm not familiar with Angular, but `subscribe` accepts different kinds of callbacks, including an `onReady` callback: https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe